# No visualizo el puntero en la pantalla cuando uso tableta Gaomon en equipo con Ubuntu 22.4

Tags: ubuntu

Hace poco he empezado a usar mi tableta GAOMON S620 en mi computadora portatil con SO Ubuntu, pero cuando voy a dibujar en alguan web con lienzo como Excalidraw o Microsoft Note, se está ocultando el puntero en la pantalla. Actualmente he instalado y desinstalado el driver que proporciona la web oficial, pero sigo teniendo el problema.

Me gustaría validar como puedo resolver el problema mencionado anteriormente, dado que no encuentro problemas relacionados en la web.

Comment: Verifica la configuración del sistema: Revisa la configuración de tu sistema operativo Ubuntu y asegúrate de que esté habilitada la funcionalidad de tableta gráfica. Puede ser necesario ajustar algunas configuraciones como la sensibilidad del lápiz o la velocidad del cursor. También puedes explorar las opciones de configuración de la tableta gráfica en el panel de control de Ubuntu, si existe.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando, he encontrado que la posible solución consiste en deshabilitar Wayland (Servidor gráfico que viene por defecto activado en Ubuntu 22.x).

Para lograr el acometido, le dí a descomentar a la linea `#WaylandEnable=false` del archivo ubicado en la ruta:

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Luego de eso, reinicié mi PC y ahora si puedo ver el puntero.

Existe una mejor documentación en este post: [How to fix screen sharing on Ubuntu 22.04](https://medium.com/@edouard.courty/how-to-fix-screen-sharing-on-ubuntu-22-04-disabling-wayland-e9eac4143c7).